# How to find all property names of label on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I want to find all property names of specific label on AgensGraph.

Which command am I use?

Answer (score 0):

There is no command to find property names.

But, you can use function "jsonb_object_keys" for it.

```
agens=# create (:v1{key:1,value:2});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
agens=# create (:v1{id:1,text:'value'});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
agens=# match (n:v1) return distinct jsonb_object_keys( properties(n) );
 jsonb_object_keys 
-------------------
 "text"
 "id"
 "value"
 "key"
(4 rows)
```